# PHP URL GET parameters inside URL parameter

Tags: php, urlencode

I am developing facebook/myspace content share buttons.  The Facebook link takes you to a URL on my website, but I need to pass additional parameters to my URL along with the parameters passed to facebook.  Here's my example:

```
http://www.facebook.com/share.php?t=MyCompany&u=http://foobar.com/test7.php?Share=161&FbShare=Facebook28
```

Do I need to escape something inside the "u" parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
$url = 'http://www.facebook.com/share.php?t=MyCompany&u='.urlencode('http://foobar.com/test7.php?Share=161&FbShare=Facebook28');
```

Comment: Perhaps I worry that I'll get it wrong and have to explain myself :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the `u` parameter, which will result in your URL looking like this:

> http://www.facebook.com/share.php?t=MyCompany&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffoobar.com%2Ftest7.php%3FShare%3D161%26FbShare%3DFacebook28

Comment: How would I decode this on foobar.com/test7.php?  Can I do regular GET_['variable' ?